# Retrieve a limited resultset from a second relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My models are as follow:

Account -> Check -> Result

```
class Account extends Model {
  public function checks() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Check');
  }
}

class Check extends Model {
  public function results() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Result');
   }
}

class Result extends Model {
  public function check() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Check');
   }
}
```

Now I am trying from a controller to do something like this:

```
$results = Account::find(1)->checks()->results()->where('result_type', 'ERROR')->orderBy('result.id', 'desc')->limit(25)->get();
```

It is clearly not working after checks(), I get and error that says results() is not defined, probably because it's looking into Account.

How can I achieve it without doing 2-3 queries ?

And I don't want to use QueryBuilder to do it "manually", I'd like to keep it Eloquent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a relationship to connect accounts and results directly, with the Check model as an intermediate.

```
// on the Account model
public function results() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Result', 'App\Check');
}
```

Then, you can just do `->results()` directly on an Account and query from there. :) In other words, your query will work fine, you just need to remove the `->checks()` call.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Thanks a bunch, just what I was looking for! +1 for being my new favorite person :)